# Is there is an entropy cost of moving an object?

Tags: classical-mechanics, kinematics, entropy

Is there an entropy cost associated with moving an object from one point to another, even if all forces involved are conservative? Or, is there some condition on what kind of move has an entropy cost?

Consider an object of mass $M+2m$ at the origin and no external forces. At time $t=0$ it releases a bullet of mass $m$ at velocity $v$ (say by a spring mechanism). It gains momentum $-mv$, moves at speed $-mv/(M+m)$ some distance $D$ in time $D(M+m)/mv$, and then releases another bullet in the opposite direction, coming to rest again. The system now consists of the object moved distance $D$, and two bullets speeding away. This certainly seems to be a higher entropy state. If we demand that the object is at the destination at time $T$, then the number of possible microstates (bullet velocities) increases with $T$. Any $v$ larger than $D(M+m)/Tm$ will do, so this set increases with T.

Roughly the same would be true for emitting EM radiation as a photon rocket.

But in GR there is spacetime swimming [1] where cyclic deformations of a body creates a geometric phase that moves it. Here there are no obvious extra microstates like above. But clearly some work is being done in the deformations, which presumably increases entropy. If they are done very slowly, however, it seems that this ought to approach an isentropic process and the swimming would be reversible. This is even more clear for the rotating on a friction-less swivel chair case (extend your arm radially, turn it to the right inducing a rotation of body plus arm, pull it in radially). Here the process seems to be fully reversible. It is also not dependent on GR.

Maybe the issue is whether there exist "remnants" like the bullets or EM radiation that can exist in multiple microstates yet generate the same macrostate of the moved object. If there is only one possible choice of remnant the system retains its entropy.

**Addendum**: As Chemomechanics pointed out in the comments, Lambert forcefully makes the case that one should not mix up thermodynamic entropy with information entropy ([2] and numerous other papers) and in particular changes in macroscopic configuration do not affect entropy. While one can argue Lambert takes a too purist view of the meaning of the concept entropy [3] I think he roughly answers my initial question. At the very least, the number of degrees of freedom affected by moving macroscopic objects (3 per object) are vastly fewer than the internal degrees of freedom that gets affected by thermodynamic processes, so entropy changes due to moving objects is dominated by any irreversible thermodynamic processes occurring rather than the macroscopic movements themselves.

This still does not tell us whether moving an object from A to B will cost us entropy, but suggests an approach to move forward: if the process is reversible there is no entropy increase. So the spacetime swimming case might be a no entropy increase case. But what about moving something in flat spacetime?

[1]: Wisdom, J. (2003). Swimming in spacetime: motion by cyclic changes in body shape. Science, 299(5614), 1865-1869. http://science.sciencemag.org/content/299/5614/1865.long

[2]: Lambert, F. L. (1999). Shuffled Cards, Messy Desks, and Disorderly Dorm Rooms-Examples of Entropy Increase? Nonsense!. J. Chem. Educ, 76(10), 1385. http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ed076p1385

[3]: Haglund, J., Jeppsson, F., & Strömdahl, H. (2010). Different senses of entropy—implications for education. Entropy, 12(3), 490-515. http://www.mdpi.com/1099-4300/12/3/490/htm

Comment: just to clarify, the actual question is just the first 2 lines right ?

Comment: You may be interested in Lambert's ["Shuffled Cards, Messy Desks, and Disorderly Dorm Rooms - Examples of Entropy Increase? Nonsense!"](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ed076p1385?journalCode=jceda8). (This is the peer-reviewed version; one version of the full text is available [here](http://entropysite.oxy.edu/shuffled_cards.html).)

Comment: @Lelouch: Yes, that is the question/questions.